# Python lxml and parsing a subtree

Tags: python, lxml

I've got a xml which looks like this:

```
<root>
<foo>
<a></a>
<b></b>
<c></c>
</foo>
<bars>
<bar>
<one>interesting</one>
<two>interesting</two>
<three>interesting</three>
</bar>
<bar>
<one>interesting</one>
<two>interesting</two>
<three>interesting</three>
</bar>
<bar>
<one>interesting</one>
<two>interesting</two>
<three>interesting</three>
</bar>
</bars>
<root>
```

I want to extract the interesting text from all the bars.
Can you tell me how to start?
I've tried to use

```
bars = etree.iterparse(xml_data, tag="bars")
```

but I couldn't iterate through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findall` method to return all matching elements.

```py
xml_data = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII' ?>
<root>
<foo>
<a></a>
<b></b>
<c></c>
</foo>
<bars>
<bar>
<one>interesting</one>
<two>interesting</two>
<three>interesting</three>
</bar>
<bar>
<one>interesting</one>
<two>interesting</two>
<three>interesting</three>
</bar>
<bar>
<one>interesting</one>
<two>interesting</two>
<three>interesting</three>
</bar>
</bars>
</root>
'''

from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(xml_data)
for bars in root.findall('.//bars'):
    print(etree.tostring(bars, method='text'))
```

Comment: But how can I extract only the text between tags (one, two and three)?
Also if <bar> has an id property like <bar id="123"> how can I extract it also?

Comment: @user2091046, To get `id` attribute, `bars.find('.//bar').get('id')`.

Comment: This code:
    `for bars in data.findall('.//bars'):
        print users.find('.//bars').get('id')
        print users.find('.//one').text
        print users.find('.//two').text`
prints only the first enrty from the XML

Comment: @user2091046, Try `for txt in root.xpath('.//bars//text()'): print txt`

Comment: that's because you write a loop `for *bars* in ...` but then in the loop you do `print *users*.find()....`. just use bars i.e. `print bars.get('id)`...

Comment: @falsetru
But there is only one "bars" element and a lot of "bar" elements.
So I had to use `data.findall('.//bar')` - that was working.
Thx for the help, couldn't done it without you guys :)